# Error during installation (DB)

Tags: database

I'm curently installing my Wordpress website in local. I've created a database called 'wordpress'. But during installation, an error say '**Impossible to select db**'. BUT, the database exists into my phpmyadmin interface.

[image]
[image]

---

The current username has all privileges and the hostname is set to 'localhost' (not %).

[image]

I really don't understand ? Wordpress say to me that it successfully connected but can't retrieve the db. My current user doesn't have password.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I guess it's saying the user doesn't have permission to read the tables in the wordpress database. Did you do the [`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` step](https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-database-for-wordpress/#using-the-mysql-client) for that user when you set up the database?

Comment: Oh, it's actually unable to switch to the database, `use wordpress;` in MySQL. This is [db_select_fail](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.2/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1086) in the code.

Comment: @Rup Sure ! The user has all privileges

Comment: You say the user `admin` has access to the DB, but the error message in the image is asking if the user `root` has access to the DB. Check your `wp-config.php` file to make sure that you've got the right username and password set for the database. (You're looking for `DB_USER ` and `DB_PASSWORD`.)